# team foundation server 2010 machine damaged

Tags: tfs

The physical computer hosting the Team Foundation Server (TFS) has been damaged. This is what I am going to do:

1. Go to my dev box, open my web app and remove any features and IDs (e.g., code version ID) related to the old TFS. I am not sure whether it is possible to do it. If it is possible, I don't know how. If you have solution, please let me know.
2. Go to a new Windows 2008, reinstall the TFS there from scratch.
3. Open my web app again and reconnect to the new TFS setup at the step 2.

Do you think these steps are doable? Or do you have another option to deal with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did the old server contain the TFS databases or just the application tier?

Comment: The old server contained the TFS databases.

Comment: Was the database backed up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the source control bindings from your solution file. Open your sln file in Notepad, and locate the Global section.
Delete everything in the subsection for the TeamFoundationVersionControl

```
Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 21
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://youroldservername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
                ......
```

It should be enough to do this, when you open the sln in VS next time, you should see the Add to sourcecontrol menu option again, and then you can add your code to your new server.
(You can delete your *.suo file and the *.vssscc file.  They will most likely be overwritten, but just in case.)

Comment: Will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot. Stock.